# Objective-C converting to C#: How can I use a .plist with multiple types in C# if Dictionary is strongly-typed?

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, cocoa-touch, windows-phone-7

The question is a bit complicated so I will try and explain. I have a custom .plist (XML Property List) file I created with Xcode. Within it is many different types of data: NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, BOOL, etc.

Here's an example:

[image]

In my code I can quickly obtain an `NSDictionary` of this entire file without knowing an data types using the following code (this is ARC code by the way). The only data types that I DO know of is that all of the keys are strings, but the values can be anything I've shown above:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)configDictionary
{
    collectorstemplateAppDelegate *appDelegate = (collectorstemplateAppDelegate*)
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
           pathForResource:appDelegate.currentPlist ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return dict;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to accomplish the same thing on C#. I'd like to take these plists and move them to my Windows Phone phone apps, keeping the same structure. I realize that I will need to write some additional code to handle the XML behind the file, but you get the idea.... I want a `Dictionary` or `HashTable` or `Collection` of something similar to what I've done above, without knowing the types of the values.

Obviously in my case something like `Dictionary<string, string>` isn't going to work for me.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Trying to shoehorn patterns from another language/IDE is not the right thing to do.  If these are properties for your application, there is already a type-safe way to access them.  Double click the Properties node of your project and click the Settings tab.  Type safe, and you can reference these settings via a static property.  Its easy to use.

Comment: These aren't just properties, it's much more complicated than that.

Comment: They *are* properties.  Of your application.  Which can be represented by *any* serializable object graph.

Comment: I'm not going to give you an in-depth explanation of how our applications work... just trust me in that they are used for more than what is visible within this question.

Comment: That's fine.  As a new user to the platform, I wanted to make sure you were aware of the Property system.  Check it out, if it doesn't fit your needs, so be it.  But there's nothing worse than trying to roll a bolder uphill when you didn't know there's an elevator right next door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here but looking for validation....

Would `Dictionary<string, object>` work? Because I know the key is a string, I would just need to cast the value to the appropriate type, correct?

```
int appleID = (int) plistDict["appleid"];
```

If this is correct or incorrect, someone please let me know.

Comment: That sounds fine and arguably better than `Hashtable` since the latter can accept non-string keys.

Answer (score 0):

[Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) is a non-generic version of Dictionary. In other words it doesn't require you to specify the types it deals with, and you can cash like you would in Objective-C.